# How to backup and restore a large MySQL database in Hibernate?

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I created an application with Java, Hibernate and MySQL (Community Server Edition).

Please answer to following questions:

1. What is different MySQL server and MySQL embedded?
2. How can I backup and restore large MySQL databases in Hibernate?
3. What is maximum number of records a MySQL embedded database can store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. MySQL embedded is not different from MySQL Server, it's just a different license so you can resell it as part of a commercial product.
2. Hibernate does not provide features for backup or restore. But you can use mysqldump if you like.
3. There's no limit.